DOMContentLoaded is null in .NET MAUI UWP
I have Xamarin forms UWP app and trying to migrate to MAUI. I am loading a local html to webview. But after migrating there are some errors in my FormsWebViewRenderer. For MAUI I am using WebView2
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<FormsWebView> e)
 {
     base.OnElementChanged(e);

     if (Control == null && Element != null)
         SetupControl();

     if (e.NewElement != null)
         SetupNewElement(e.NewElement);

     if (e.OldElement != null)
         DestroyOldElement(e.OldElement);
 }

Here Control.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded is always null. There is no ScriptReceived also in WebView2
  void SetupControl()
  {

      var control = new WebView2();
      _resolver = new LocalFileStreamResolver(this);

      SetNativeControl(control);

      FormsWebView.CallbackAdded += OnCallbackAdded;
      Control.NavigationStarting += OnNavigationStarting;
      Control.NavigationCompleted += OnNavigationCompleted;
      Control.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += OnDOMContentLoaded;
      //Control.CoreWebView2.ScriptReceived += OnScriptReceived;

      SetNativeControl(control);

      OnControlChanged?.Invoke(this, control);
  }

private async void OnDOMContentLoaded(CoreWebView2 sender, CoreWebView2DOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{
    if (Element == null) return;

    // Add Injection Function
    await Control.ExecuteScriptAsync(FormsWebView.InjectedFunction);

    // Add Global Callbacks
    if (Element.EnableGlobalCallbacks)
        foreach (var callback in FormsWebView.GlobalRegisteredCallbacks)
            await Control.ExecuteScriptAsync(FormsWebView.GenerateFunctionScript(callback.Key));

    // Add Local Callbacks
    foreach (var callback in Element.LocalRegisteredCallbacks)
        await Control.ExecuteScriptAsync(FormsWebView.GenerateFunctionScript(callback.Key));

    Element.HandleContentLoaded();
}

Also when using in Xamarin I has this method,
void LoadLocalFile(string source)
{
    var src = Control.BuildLocalStreamUri("/", source);
    Control.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(src, _resolver);
}

There is no BuildLocalStreamUri and NavigateToLocalStreamUri in MAUI
LocalFileStreamResolver.cs
  public class LocalFileStreamResolver : IUriToStreamResolver
  {
      private readonly WeakReference<FormsWebViewRenderer> Reference;

      public LocalFileStreamResolver(FormsWebViewRenderer renderer)
      {
          Reference = new WeakReference<FormsWebViewRenderer>(renderer);
      }

      public IAsyncOperation<IInputStream> UriToStreamAsync(Uri uri)
      {
          if (uri == null)
              throw new Exception("Uri supplied is null.");

          var path = uri.AbsolutePath;
          return GetContent(path)?.AsAsyncOperation();
      }

      private async Task<IInputStream> GetContent(string path)
      {
          if (!Reference.TryGetTarget(out FormsWebViewRenderer renderer))
              return default(IInputStream);

          try
          {
              if (renderer.GetBaseUrl() == null)
                  throw new Exception("Base URL was not set, could not load local content");

              var f = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(string.Concat(renderer.GetBaseUrl(), path)));
              var stream = await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

              return stream;
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              throw new Exception(e.Message);
          }
      }
  }


I notice that DOMContentLoaded is a method, can you tell us more about where the Null appears?

in this line :  Control.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += OnDOMContentLoaded;

Could you please post the full error log about this problem?
